# Using Ajax in a .net project to call a .aspx.cs function NOT WORKING

Tags: asp.net, jquery, asp.net-ajax

Im using Ajax in a .net project (isn't MVC.net). I want to call a function of my .aspx.cs from a JScript Function.

This is my JScript code:

```
    $("a#showQuickSearch").click(function () {
        if ($("#quick_search_controls").is(":hidden")) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Default.aspx/SetInfo",
                data: "{showQuickSearch}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
               success: function(response) {
                     alert(response.d);
               }

            });
            $("#quick_search_controls").slideDown("slow");
            $("#search_controls").hide();
            $("#search").hide();
        } else {
            $("#quick_search_controls").hide();
        }

    });
```

And this is my .aspx.cs Function:

```
   [WebMethod]
    public string SetInfo(string strChangeSession)
    {
        Label1.Text = strChangeSession;
        return "This is a test";
    }
```

The problem is that my .aspx.cs function is not being called and isn't updating the label.text.

Comment: I don't think you can do it like that. Your server side should be static to be a page method, and as a static method you won't be able to access the Label as it's a member of that page *instance*

Comment: The quality of a question is directly proportional to (the number of digits in the username + 1) * (SO points / number of months since registration). Needless to say, this question doesn't rate highly.

Answer (score 1):

Try making your function static.

```
[WebMethod]
    public static string SetInfo(string strChangeSession)
    {
        //Label1.Text = strChangeSession; this wont work
        return "This is a test";
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, how do you access a control from within a static method?

Comment: You don't, I overlooked that part and commented it.

Answer (score 1):

`data: "{showQuickSearch}"` is not valid JSON.

Here's how a valid JSON would look like:

```
data: JSON.stringify({ strChangeSession: 'showQuickSearch' })
```

Also your PageMethod needs to be static:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string SetInfo(string strChangeSession)
{
    return "This is a test";
}
```

which obviously means that you cannot access any page elements such as labels and stuff. It is inside your success callback that you could now use the result of the PageMethod to update some label or whatever.

Comment: Do you see the request being sent in FireBug? What does the server respond to this request?

Comment: This won't work because the server side method is an instance method. PageMethods must be static. Check Henlet Escaño's answer

Answer (score 0):

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Default.aspx/SetInfo",
            data: "{'strChangeSession':'showQuickSearch'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(response) {
                 alert(response.d);
           },
          error: function (xhr, status, error) {

                var msg = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                alert(msg.Message);
            }
        });
```

And your backend code:

```
 [WebMethod]
 public static string SetInfo(string strChangeSession)
 {
   return "Response ";
 }
```